# How in doughnut ChartWidget remove values/scales at x and y-coordinates

Tags: laravel-filament

I try to customize my doughnut ChartWidget reading docs :
https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/dashboard#customizing-the-widgets-grid

a) But I need to remove values/scales at x and y-coordinates :
[image]

as they have no sense in this case

b) When I put mouse over elements of doughnut - it shows label and value in popup hint
If there is a way alwasys to show these label and value for any element

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.28.0",
"filament/filament": "^3.0-stable",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add $options to you chart, somewhere in the alpine/js the x and y axis are set to defaults, that's why it shows the x and y axis. When you add the following code the x and y axis will be hidden:

```
protected static ?array $options = [
    'scales' => [
        'x' => [
            'display' => false,
        ],
        'y' => [
            'display' => false,
        ],
    ],
];
```